# How to add large amount of text in android?

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

For my app i want to add a FAQ page which contains large amount of text. Some of it has to be bold, underlined. I have an faq_xml with a scrollview. How do i add this large amount of text in a well displayed format? I read some online forums saying about using the html format. I couldn't understand. Some help would be appreciatd!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:maxLines = "any integer"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string containing HTML code. This String will then be used in a webView that you will make in you faq_xml.

[Check this thread..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204336/how-to-add-external-css-file-on-html-page-in-android)

You can assign your html code to a string and then apply that css file you learned to create in the above mentioned thread.

Then call the webView like

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", YourStringHere, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

[For your ease check out this thread..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css)